# How I can recover the type of an Icon Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I use an Icon Ant Design, I want to recover the type of my Icon for use it for changing the color if she is clicked. But type is not defined

```
<Icon                                
     type="highlight"                                
     onClick={(() =>this.setState({ iconSelected: this.props.type,}),                                    
          () => console.log(this.props.type))
     }

     style={{height: 50, width: 50, fontSize: 20, color: iconSelected == this.props.type ? "#1890ff" : "grey"}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, `this` does not refer to the Icon itself.  What you want to access is the event object which you need to pass as a parameter to the handler function.  You can then access the event's `target`, which is the DOM node of the icon itself, which has a `data-icon` attribute containing the icon name which you can access using vanilla DOM methods:

```
<Icon type="mail" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-icon'))}/>
```

This will log the icon name, but you can do whatever you need with it.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help!

Comment: But now, I'am blocked to how check  if the type of icon is that selected for the color? ( in the style because type is undefined)